# How to add a Schema Filter to just one Swashbuckle api document version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I have an issue, I use Swashbuckle 4 and it doesn't support polymorph, I found two filters that do that.
One DocumentFilter and one SchemaFilter.

They work like charme.

But now I have an issue, I add a second version to my api.
But I have a polymorph model which is just supported by version 2.

But I found no way to add these filters just to one api version, because they are added at Startup to the SwaggerGenOptions.

I'm little bit shocked that Swashbuckle does not seem to support Filters per version, because versions are exactly to separate two code worlds in one project.

Any ideas?

Comment: May this article help you https://dev.to/htissink/versioning-asp-net-core-apis-with-swashbuckle-making-space-potatoes-v-x-x-x-3po7

Comment: @gandalf Unfortunately not, because he also just add the two filters globaly.

Comment: A code sample will be useful to reduce the time it takes to reproduce this issue

Comment: @HelderSepulveda It would be a lot of Code and a lot of work to provide that. But you can just take the code from the postet link here in the comments.
And than look at the "// Apply the filters" section, that two applied fitlers, are applied to all api versions. And I want to apply such a filter to just one API version.

Comment: It's on your best interest to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
without that most questions get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we need an example is because there are different ways of approaching versioning. I'm not sure how you are doing it, but usually a Model is versioned with a new class with the same name, but in a different Namespace, in which case there is no issue. Register all your Filters. They should know how to tell if the object being processed is the one they know how to handle. I'm not familiar with IDocumentFilter, but for ISchemaFilter:

```
    public class MyV1SchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.SystemType != MyProject.Models.v1.MyModel) return;
            /// configure v1 schema
        }
    }

    public class MyV2SchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.SystemType != MyProject.Models.v2.MyModel) return;
            /// configure v2 schema
        }
    }
```

You could also put it all in one Filter:

```
    public class MySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.SystemType == MyProject.Models.v1.MyModel)
            {
                /// configure v1 schema
            }
            else if (context.SystemType == MyProject.Models.v2.MyModel)
            {
                /// configure v2 schema
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are doing it in a way where both versions are somehow represented by the same Class, then maybe you need to separate them.

DocumentFilterContext seems like it has enough data in there for it to know which version it was passed, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue, where i wanted to "hide" schemas (classes) that doesn't apply to a specific Document.

I ended up by adding a custom Attribute on the class that needs to be applied only to specific doc version. and added this Filter in the end of the pipeline.

basically, it filters all schemas that doesnt applied to a specific ApiVersion(document version)

```cs
    using System;
    
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustomSwaggerSchemaIdAttribute : Attribute
    {        
        public CustomSwaggerSchemaIdAttribute(string schemaPrefix)
        {
            SchemaPrefix = schemaPrefix;
        }        
        public CustomSwaggerSchemaIdAttribute(string schemaPrefix, string showOnlyOnDocumentVersion)
        {
            SchemaPrefix = schemaPrefix;
            ShowOnlyOnDocumentVersion = showOnlyOnDocumentVersion;
        }

        public string SchemaPrefix { get; private set; }
        public string ShowOnlyOnDocumentVersion { get; private set; }
    }
```

then added a Document filter on the swagger pipeline:

```cs
    public class SchemaDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            //swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Values.First().
            var types = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetCustomAttribute<CustomSwaggerSchemaIdAttribute>() != null);
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var attr = type.GetCustomAttribute<CustomSwaggerSchemaIdAttribute>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.ShowOnlyOnDocumentVersion) && attr.ShowOnlyOnDocumentVersion != swaggerDoc.Info.Version)
                {
                    var id = OpenApiOptionsExtension.DefaultSchemaIdSelector(type);
                    context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```