# How can a filter be applied to a single swagger document with Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am generating multiple swagger documents with my ASP.NET Core web service. I have some filters that I want to only apply to one document, but it appears that they apply to all documents.

I have an `IDocumentFilter`, `IOperationFilter`, `IParameterFilter`, and `ISchemaFilter` that I only want to apply in one case. When I load the swagger pages for the other document types, my filters are applied. I can debug and see that the filters are appended (probably, the debugger won't show me the types but the number of filters go up) onto a single `SwaggerGenOptions` in `AddSwaggerGen`.

Below is what I use in my startup code. The `OpenApiConfigOptions` is just a singleton set up elsewhere that has some info like the API name and description.

I thought since the `SwaggerDoc` extension method does set up multiple documents that it would be using a new `SwaggerGenOptions` for each document. Is there something I'm missing in my setup?

I also don't see a way to, within the filter itself, check which document is being loaded and skip the filter if it isn't the right document. That would not be an ideal solution but could be a workaround if I could find that value inside of the filter.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterMyOpenApi<TExamplesAssembly>(this IServiceCollection services, OpenApiConfigOptions options)
        {
            services.RegisterOpenApiDocument(options, "BASIC");
            var scheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Description = "basic authentication",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "basic"
            };
            services.AddFilteredSecurityScheme("BASIC", "basic", scheme);

            services.RegisterOpenApiDocument(options, "ANONYMOUS");

            services.RegisterOpenApiDocument(options, "MYSPECIALTYPE");

            return services;
        }

        private static void RegisterOpenApiDocument(this IServiceCollection services, OpenApiConfigOptions options, string type)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                var info = new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = options.ServiceTitle,
                    Description = options.ServiceDescription,
                    Version = options.Version
                };
                c.SwaggerDoc(type.ToLowerInvariant(), info);

                if (type == "MYSPECIALTYPE")
                {
                    // Azure APIM does not understand reference types for enums
                    c.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();

                    c.DocumentFilter<MySpecialDocumentFilter>(options);
                    c.OperationFilter<MySpecialOperationFilter>();
                    c.ParameterFilter<MySpecialParameterFilter>();
                    c.SchemaFilter<MySpecialSchemaFilter>();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It is not clear to me what the real issue is. In order to avoid X/Y, can you please elaborate what your original problem is? E.g. are you trying to hide some attributes? BR

Comment: Well, mainly I'm applying a bunch of special rules that do transformations in order to get Azure API Management to display my API correctly. You can see one of them is `UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums`. I want to use a shared definition for most of my documents, but I need to use the inline version for my APIM document.

Comment: Some other things the filters do is add custom extensions that are only used in one document, change the parameter description for when a parameter is an array of enums, and set the parameter style to `form` and disable `explode` in order for an API to work well with Power Automate.

Comment: It looks like [this PR](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/1480) would enable the workaround I mentioned for `IDocumentFilter` where I could check the document name and skip the filter if it isn't the one I want. Would need to be applied to all of the filters, though, and this has been sitting since February with no reply from the repo owner :(

Comment: I see. Just thinking loud now, would design-first be a solution?

Comment: I don't think that changing the overall API design to work for the current feature set of one way of using the API is a good solution in this case. The filters I'm adding are generally not things I _want_ to apply, I just have to due to the limitations of the consumer. For example, using inline definitions for enums. I'd rather have the reference type be used but that isn't supported in APIM. Design first would mean either not using enums or maybe rethinking my architecture so that my service only supports this one consumer and there's some transformation service for other consumers.

Comment: I think [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093955/how-to-add-a-schema-filter-to-just-one-swashbuckle-api-document-version) was looking for the same sort of thing, not sure if the suggested workaround worked for them.

Comment: I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/1922) for the workaround I mentioned.

Comment: Looked into the SO-link in "I think this person was looking ...", and the answer in that question indicates how I organized my previous API-project (namespace per version). 

I used 
- ISchemaFilter to fix arrays
- IDocumentFilter to ignore some of the models
- IDocumentFilter to ignore parameters annotated with custom attribute
- ISchemaFilter to ignore properties annotated with custom attribute
- IOperationFilter to remove API-version. That project is not hosted on Azure, but I'm working on a functions based Azure API these days,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225727/discussion-between-garie-and-roar-s).

Comment: You're maybe right, killed my answer. BR

Comment: Hi @garie, if you've ever found a solution, could you point me to the right direction about how you would use `UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums` within a document filter, to get it applied only to a single document? This is exactly what I would need now. Thank you in advance!